# ¿Cómo verificar que el orden correcto de una matricula de auto con str e int?

Tags: python, string

necesito ayuda, es que estoy realizando un ejercicio sobre matriculas y uno de las condiciones indica que la matricula no tiene que tener números intercalados entre las letras, solamente los números tienen que estar al final de las letras, para ser más claro, la matricula correcta debe ser esta "HIY456" y no "H2I4Y6"

Comment: ¿Son patentes de Argentina? podrías validar con expresiones regulares 3 letras + 3 números. ¿Esto te serviría?

Comment: Según leo, la condición es que no puede haber un número a la izquierda de una letra. Si es así, guarda el primer caracter en una variable `aux`, luego con un `for`, recorre letra por letra `c`. Si `aux` es numero y `c` es letra, ya no cumple y se puede terminar el `for`, de lo contrario `aux = c` y sigue la siguiente iteración. Si nunca entró en el `if`, entonces es una matrícula válida. Para verificar si un caracter o cadena es letra o numero, usa `isalpha()`, o `isnumeric()`. Lo anterior se puede hacer con regex: `'(\d)+[A-Z]'`, si hace match, entonces no es matrícula válida.

Comment: Y que has intentado?, que error te sale?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Esta seria una forma de solucionar tu problema

```py
def ordernarMatricula(matricula):
    #Cre variables para que almacenes letras y numeros respectivamente
    letras = ''
    numeros = ''

    #recorre tu cadena
    for m in matricula:
        #valida si el caracter que se esta recorriendo es una letra con la funcion isalpha()
        if m.isalpha():
            # si es una letra entonces la agregamos a la variable que creamos para almacenarla
            letras += m
        else:
            #de lo contrario si es un numero la agregaremos a la variables de numeros
            numeros += m

    #retornamos la matricula ordenada, primero letras y luego numeros
    return letras + numeros

ordernarMatricula('H2I4Y6')
```

Comment: La pregunta pide validar la matrícula, no ordenarla.